# Selection with jquery in Div Container

Tags: jquery

i have an selection problem with jquery, i hope you can help me, i have a list, and when remove a div i will give the divs new id numbers 0-....

this i use for php array and sessions.

my html:

```
<div id="rezeile_1" class="lcolumn">
    <div class="lrow">
        <input id="zid_1" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input id="zre_1" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input id="ztext_1" type="hidden" value="test 1"> 
        <a onclick="remove('rezeile_1')" href="#one">(-)</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="rezeile_2" class="lcolumn">
    <div class="lrow">
        <input id="zid_2" type="hidden" value="2">
        <input id="zre_2" type="hidden" value="2">
        <input id="ztext_2" type="hidden" value="test 2"> 
        <a onclick="remove('rezeile_2')" href="#one">(-)</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

now i want select with jquery the inputs for change the attributes

this is my jquery for now:

```
$('[id^=rezeile_]').each(function () {
    var temp = $(this).next('div > [id^=ztext_]').val();
    var attrib1 = $(this).next('div > [id^=ztext_]').attr('id');
    var attrib2 = $(this).next('div > [id^=zre_]').attr('id');
    alert(temp);
    alert(attrib1);
    alert(attrib2);
});
```

but i become always undefined alerts, can you give me a hint?

thank you!

Comment: Use classes not ids with iterative numbers. It's what they were designed for - to prevent headaches like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this;

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kjSbj/

```
$('[id^=rezeile_]').each(function (index,val) {
    var temp = $(val).find('div > [id^=ztext_]').val();
    var attrib1 = $(val).find('div > [id^=ztext_]').attr('id');
    var attrib2 = $(val).find('div > [id^=zre_]').attr('id');
    alert(temp);
    alert(attrib1);
    alert(attrib2);
});
```

But I suggest you to use classes instead of id's for the repeating elments

Answer (score 1):

Use classes for this kind of repeated structure, and not ids with iterative numbers. It's what they were designed for - to prevent headaches like this.

Try this approach instead:

```
<div id="rezeile_1" class="lcolumn rezeile">
    <div class="lrow">
        <input class="zid" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input class="zre" type="hidden" value="1">
        <input class="ztext" type="hidden" value="test 1"> 
        <a href="#one" class="remove">(-)</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="rezeile_2" class="lcolumn rezeile">
    <div class="lrow">
        <input class="zid" type="hidden" value="2">
        <input class="zre" type="hidden" value="2">
        <input class="ztext" type="hidden" value="test 2"> 
        <a href="#one" class="remove">(-)</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.rezeile').each(function () {
    var temp = $('.ztext', $(this)).val(); // gets the ztext value for the current instance of .rezeile
    alert(temp);
}); 

$('.remove').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('rezeile').remove();
});
```

Also note, I removed your `onclick` attribute as it was outdated, and meant that it needed changing for each specific instance of the group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('[id^=rezeile_]').each(function () {
    var temp = $(this).find('input[id^=ztext_]').val();
    var attrib1 = $(this).find('input[id^=ztext_]').attr('id');
    var attrib2 = $(this).find('input[id^=zre_]').attr('id');
    alert(temp);
    alert(attrib1);
    alert(attrib2);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on keeping your crazy ID selectors:

```
$('[id^=rezeile_]').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this); 
    var temp = $('div > [id^=ztext_]', $this).val();
    var attrib1 = $('div > [id^=ztext_]', $this).attr('id');
    var attrib2 = $('div > [id^=zre_]', $this).attr('id');
    alert(temp);
    alert(attrib1);
    alert(attrib2);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eqWdY/1/)